# OutputRaw text for checkboxes

Tags: tapestry

I would like to use the Tapestry Checklist-Component, but would like it to render the checkbox titles as raw output. I want to use HTML code inside the checkbox titles.

Is this possible in an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, tapestry escapes any special characters in the label.

```
writer.element("label", "for", clientId);
writer.write(model.getLabel()); // MarkupWriter.write(...) escapes HTML chars
writer.end();
```

You will probably need to write a [mixin](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-mixins.html) to achieve this. The mixin will tweak the label [element](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/dom/Element.html)s after the checklist has rendered.